# The best structure for connect and disconnect MySQL database using a PHP class

Tags: php, class, database-connection

I wrote my database class in PHP. `__construct()` method will automatically connect the application to the database and `__destruct()` method will automatically close the connection from database.
I included this class at top of the main page `index.php`.
So far, please tell me is it a good way to work with database or not?

My next question belongs to Transactions. I earned this error while I'm working with Transaction:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Is this error because of the structure of my database class ? When the database connection will disconnect in my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a good way but the error is not becouse of this structure. One reason for this error is that you have an open multiple result set for example when you executing a stored procedure which return multiple result set (multiple SELECT). When you executing something like this you have to consume all the results or at least close the result sets.

Another reason could be that you are having an opened transaction and the driver/databse doen't support nested transactions.

Comment: Peter, I've used "MultipleActiveResultSets" => true. But the problem is still alive :(

Comment: You have to find (step by step) where are you retrieving multiple result set and handle it correctly. Until that, you can't query your database.